# Java concurrency, monitor for Lock

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I am using Lock in my app and I wonder what is monitor in this case:

```
public class BoundedBuffer {
    private final String[] buffer;
    private final int capacity;

    private int front;
    private int rear;
    private int count;

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    private final Condition notFull = lock.newCondition();
    private final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();

    public BoundedBuffer(int capacity) {
        super();

        this.capacity = capacity;

        buffer = new String[capacity];
    }

    public void deposit(String data) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();

        try {
            while (count == capacity) {
                notFull.await();
            }

            buffer[rear] = data;
            rear = (rear + 1) % capacity;
            count++;

            notEmpty.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

In this example when invoking deposit method whole object is monitor or only lock ? This is like using `synchronize(this)` which lock whole instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole object doesn't have any special meaning here. Monitor means the combination of Lock  and Condition so it's possible to atomically perform check and block until something happens, see [wiki Monitor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)).

`lock.lock ()`is similar to `synchronized` keyword but `Lock` gives more flexibility. Among others it can create conditions which allow to notify about full/empty status and are connected to this `Lock`.